# Randomize list without same entry successively

Tags: python, list, random

```
order_list_raw = []
for i in range(1, 73):
    order_list_raw.append(1)
    order_list_raw.append(2)
    order_list_raw.append(3)
```

How can I create the same list with a randomized order but without having the same entry successively (e.g. "1, 3, 2" is okay but not "1, 1, 3").

For randomization I would create a new list like this:

```
order_list = random.sample(order_list_raw, len(order_list_raw))
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Do you mean `random.shuffle()`?

Comment: Wouldn't random.shuffle also result in a random list where two successive entries could be the same?

Comment: Expected output is a list with 72 entries only consisting of the numbers 1, 2 and 3. This list should be in random order/shuffled. But every consecutive entry should not be the same. So something like [1,3,2,3,2,1,2,1,3...] would be good, but not [1,1,3,2,2,1,3,3...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution would be:

```
result = []
 
for i in range(72):
    options = [1, 2, 3]
    
    try:
        last_item = result[-1]
        options.remove(last_item)
    except IndexError:
        pass
    
    result.append(random.choice(options))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3]
```

Here we simply take our options, check what the last value in the list is and delete that value from the options. Then we take a random value from the left over options, and append it to the list.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you want to generate the input data randomly then you can use this solution.

```
import random
b=[]

for i in range(0,73):

    x=random.randint(1,10)

    if len(b)==0 or b[-1]!=x:
        b.append(x)

print(b)
```

Output :

[6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 5, 3, 8, 1, 5, 4, 9, 4, 9, 8, 6, 9, 2, 1, 5, 8, 6, 1, 9, 6, 9, 3, 6, 5, 7, 9, 1, 9, 5, 9, 3, 4, 3, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 9, 1, 4, 9, 2, 1, 5, 7, 1, 10, 2, 4, 2, 1, 7, 1, 5, 4, 1, 2]

But in case if your input data is fixed, then you can try this solution as below.

```
a=[1,1,4]
b=[]
c=[[b.append(i)  for i in a if len(b)==0 or b[-1]!=i]for j in range(0,100)]
print(b)
```

Output :

[1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 4]